# I can't restore attributes the previous cell that I deselected

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I have a UIViewController in mainstoryboard, and it contains a tableview, it just shows the labels, not exciting things. And when I click one of the cells it push me to the detailVC. The problem is starting here, when I come back from detailVC, the cell that i pushed, is still looking selected. And it looks gross. I tried everything that i can. And lastly cells are custom cell.

P.s.: I have to use swift 2.3 in this project.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableVieww.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellNew", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AltKategoriNewCell
        let data = self.katData[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabelNew?.text = data["CatogryName"] as? String

        return cell
    }

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = tableVieww.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellNew", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AltKategoriNewCell
    let data = self.katData[indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabelNew?.text = data["CatogryName"] as? String

    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    cell.textLabelNew?.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()

    urunlerList.altKatDic = self.katData[indexPath.row]
    performSegueWithIdentifier("urunlerList", sender: nil)
}

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let cell = tableVieww.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellNew", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AltKategoriNewCell

    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    cell.textLabelNew?.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
}
```

**TableView**
[image: TableView]

**Attributes**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing that is wrong is that you are dequeueing the cell in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` methods. `UITableView` does not expect you to do that there. If you need to get the cell in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, you can ask

```
 let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
```

`UITableViewCell` has `selectedBackgroundView` and, `UILabel` has `highlightedTextColor`. Knowing that, you can just set up appropriately your cell, and then you won't need to modify its properties on selection/deselection, like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellNew", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AltKategoriNewCell
    if nil == cell.selectedBackgroundView {
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = UIView()
        cell.selectedBackgroundView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    }
    let data = self.katData[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabelNew?.text = data["CatogryName"] as? String

    return cell
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    urunlerList.altKatDic = self.katData[indexPath.row]
    performSegueWithIdentifier("urunlerList", sender: nil)
}
```

Having this, your implementation of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` can be removed.